# Jest spy on React useRef hook not being used after updating Jest to 24.9

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, react-hooks, spyon

When I used jest 22.4 I had a test like the following

```
it ('should blah', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValueOnce(blahMock);
  const comp = shallowWithIntl(<Blah />);
  const compShallow = comp.first().shallow();

  expect(spy).toBeCalled()
});
```

This works with jest 22.4, not in jest 24.9. I'm not certain that version is the problem as our team uplifted a few things. I will paste our current and old package json devdependencies area below.

Old package.json devdependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.14.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^1.4.8",
    "enzyme-redux": "^0.2.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-terra": "^2.5.0",
    "generic-site-app": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^1.1.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.4",
    "jsdom": "11.11.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "orion-toolkit-js": "^3.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-on-rails": "7.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "stylelint": "^9.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^5.0.0",
    "terra-markdown": "^2.24.0",
    "terra-slide-panel": "^3.3.0",
    "terra-toolkit": "^4.26.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
```

New package.json devdependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.14.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "browserslist-config-terra": "^1.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^1.4.8",
    "enzyme-redux": "^0.2.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-terra": "^2.5.0",
    "generic-site-app": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^1.1.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.4",
    "jsdom": "11.11.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-on-rails": "7.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "stylelint": "^9.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^5.0.0",
    "terra-aggregate-translations": "^1.4.0",
    "terra-markdown": "^2.24.0",
    "terra-slide-panel": "^3.3.0",
    "terra-toolkit": "^5.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  }
```

Comment: Soved by changing 'const blahRef = useRef(null)' to 'const blahRef = React.useRef(null)'